# Calculating height: fit-content dynamically using calc

Tags: html, css

i am trying to calculate the height of a navbar that changes according to the viewport i want to make the next div start underneath but am not really getting how i can use calc and calculate the right hieght i have this code below which  had to set manually with try and error and it works perfectly but i wanted to ask how to use the calc to calculate the em of the hieght to i can use it, below are the codes and i have also set the em for the body

HTML

```
<nav>
        <h1 class="brand">Brand</h1>
        <button class="burger-button">
          <span class="bar-span"></span>
          <span class="bar-span"></span>
          <span class="bar-span"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="link-menu">
          <a href="#" class="">Login</a>
          <a href="# class="">Sign up</a>
          <a href="#" class="">Login</a>
          <a href="#" class="">Login</a>
        </div>
```

```
:root {
    font-size: calc(1em + 0.4vw);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```
nav {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    background-color: var(--dark);
    border-bottom: 0.187em solid var(--bootstrap-primary);
    height: fit-content;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    
}
```

and here am talking about

```
.link-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-content: center;
    background-color: var(--dark);
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.24em; /* this part i wanted to calculate automatically or dynamically*/
    width: 50%;
    height: calc(100vh - 2.24em);
    opacity: 0.8;
    transform: translate(-100%);
}
```

although code works as intended currently but I think it will be better if I can calculate it dynamically instead of manually.

Comment: I dont think it is possible with css alone. You would need to use javascript to consider the height change dynamically. I tried doing with css as well ..but that is where the limits are reached with css.

Comment: to set an absolute child visually under its parent , i would set the parent in relative position then set the children to `top:100%` to see it right on the bottom, no matter the height of the parent. You probably over thought it :) if it has to start from the middle, then `top:50%` . to move it back up to cover the whole thing, then `top:0;`  will do. unless i misunderstand what you try to do (your code do not reproduce your issue as it is)

Comment: I am probably overthinking yea, and yes you are right i do not actually have any issue i was just thinking maybe there might be a case where the height might change , but then i think the em is accounting for this. Thanks anyway.